# PHP merge associative arrays with duplicate keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$array1 = [
  ['State'=>'Utah', 'users'=>5],
  ['State'=>'California', 'users'=>10]
]

$array2 = [
  ['State'=>'Utah', 'emails'=>18],
  ['State'=>'Arizona', 'emails'=>32],
  ['State'=>'California', 'emails'=>28],
]
```

How would I merge them so that it will become like this:

```
$mergedArray = [
  ['State'=>'Utah', 'users'=>5, 'emails'=>18],
  ['State'=>'Arizona', 'emails'=>32],
  ['State'=>'California', 'users'=>10, 'emails'=>28]
]
```

I tried array_merge but it only kept data from the first array.

Edit: Notice how the length and order of the array can be different.

Comment: Thanks, you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [***array_replace_recursive***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) function:

```
$array1 = ['Utah'=>['users'=>5],'California'=>['users'=>10]];
$array2 = ['Utah'=>['emails'=>18],'California'=>['emails'=>28]];

$result = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [Utah] => Array
        (
            [users] => 5
            [emails] => 18
        )

    [California] => Array
        (
            [users] => 10
            [emails] => 28
        )
)
```

---

**Update:**
Though you have changed your initial requirements I also have solution for your ***new*** input data.
Used functions: `array_merge` and `array_values`

```
// user data
$array1 = [
  ['State'=>'Utah', 'users'=>5],
  ['State'=>'California', 'users'=>10]
];

// email data
$array2 = [
  ['State'=>'Utah', 'emails'=>18],
  ['State'=>'Arizona', 'emails'=>32],
  ['State'=>'California', 'emails'=>28],
];

$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $item) {
    if (isset($result[$item['State']])) {
        $result[$item['State']] = array_merge($result[$item['State']], $item);
    } else {
        $result[$item['State']] = $item;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [State] => Utah
            [users] => 5
            [emails] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [State] => California
            [users] => 10
            [emails] => 28
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [State] => Arizona
            [emails] => 32
        )
)
```

Comment: I just realized the structure of the array is different than I thought, otherwise this works

Comment: I updated the question the show what the array is actually like

Comment: @Jordash, and what's not working? I've tested on your new arrays and it gives me: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [State] => Utah
            [users] => 5
            [emails] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [State] => California
            [users] => 10
            [emails] => 28
        )

)` as you expected

Comment: I figured out why it is working in  a simple example and not in the full example, I updated the question above